# Finding the right number of buttons/CTAs to maximise enquiries

Tags: website-design, call-to-action

I'm designing what is effectively a brochure-ware website for which the primary function is maximise the number of enquiries for the service.

The are quite a few in-depth pages of information about the service which are structured to urge the reader to continue to the next page, but also a number of call to actions (listed below). I'm wary of putting too many call to actions on each page, and this is where your help is appreciated...

If all options are to appear on a screen:

- **View packages**: Linking the user to a page that indicates 3 levels of service based on company size, but prices are not included.
- **Request pricing**: There is no set pricing structure, the user will need to get in touch and is directed to an enquiry form, and will ultimately be sent an email of information.
- **Request demonstration**: Some users will want to see it in action first, the user will need to get in touch, is directed to an enquiry form, and will receive a one-to-one demo.
- **Download brochure**: Opens a PDF / downloads PDF
- **Request a call back**: Not sure about the value of this.

Does it matter on how many CTAs are at the bottom of each page, and simply a design challenge, or are the users likely to suffer from choice overload?

Does that make sense?

Comment: Ideally you get one or two (generally a Do Something with a learn more as a link after the CTA) and no more as Lisa's answer suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calls to action is the term reserved for the main focus of the page. Other links are not calls to action.

You should have a maximum of two calls to action on a web page. They are the main large buttons e.g. view our explanation video ... or mainly signup!

Number of other links is more of a design issue. Generally the trend at the moment is to have fat footers with lots of links. Look up fat footers ...you will find lots of good design examples.

The key is to organise them logically ... generally people do this with headings.

Comment: Thanks, Lisa, for the good tips and rapid response. Your response has clarified my next steps. Much appreciated.

Comment: Nice summary of call-to-actions. However why do you say there should be a maximum of two on a web page? Why not limit it to just one, or why not three?

Comment: I think its what Steve Krug recommends for one. In fact some people even talk about primary CTA and secondary CTA. Beyond that they should be links. I like his view that a webpage is a billboard that people are flying by so design it like that. Very few simple messages...